# Casperjs Shows Phantomjs Crash

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I got a little bit serious problem with casperjs.
I try to pull 640 rows of data from website. The first step is found total data found (which is 640), and after that I iterate all found data and store to database fia sendAJAX (synchronously) 
Here is my code

```
try{
    casper.then(function(){
        if(total_page > 0){
            var total_hotel = 0;

            //this.echo("Hit here");

            for(var j=0; j<listHotelPage.length; j++){
                total_hotel += listHotelPage[j].listHotelObj.length;
            }

            //save hotels amount on related city
            var save = this.evaluate(function(total_hotel, city_code){
                var wsurl       = "http://localhost:9000/Cities/saveHotelNum";
                var data        = new Object();
                data.cityCode   = city_code;
                data.hotelNum   = total_hotel;
                __utils__.sendAJAX(wsurl, "POST" , data, false, { contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
            }, total_hotel, city_code);

            this.echo("Saved Hotel With Amount = "+total_hotel);

            //save all hotels found on related city
            //this.echo("Insert 1");

            this.evaluate(function(listHotelPage, city_code){
                var save_hotel_url  = "http://localhost:9000/Hotels/saveHotelRest";
                var data            = new Object();

                window.__utils__.echo("List Hotel Page Length :"+listHotelPage.length);
                window.__utils__.echo("City Code :"+city_code);

                for(var i=0; i<listHotelPage.length; i++){
                    window.__utils__.echo("Iteration #"+i);
                    for(var j=0; j<listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj.length; j++){
                        data                = new Object();
                        data.hotelCode      = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].hotel_code;
                        data.hotelName      = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].hotel_name;
                        data.hotelAddress   = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].hotel_address;
                        data.photo          = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].base64img;
                        data.hotelStar      = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].star_score;
                        data.cityCode       = city_code;

                        __utils__.sendAJAX(save_hotel_url, "POST" , data, false, { contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });

                        var room_length     = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj.length;
                        var room_data       = new Object();
                        var save_room_url   = "http://localhost:9000/Rooms/saveRoomRest";

                        //window.__utils__.echo("Save 2.5");

                        for(var k=0; k<room_length; k++){
                            room_data = new Object();
                            room_data.hotelCode     = data.hotelCode;
                            room_data.categoryName  = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj[k].room_category;
                            room_data.roomService   = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj[k].room_service;
                            room_data.roomPrice     = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj[k].room_price;
                            room_data.available     = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj[k].available;
                            room_data.currencyCode  = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj[k].currencyCode;
                            //window.__utils__.echo("Save 3");
                            __utils__.sendAJAX(save_room_url, "POST" , room_data, false, { contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
                        }

                        window.__utils__.echo("Save #"+i);
                    }
                }

            }, listHotelPage, city_code);   

        }
        else if(total_page == null || total_page <= 0 || total_page == ""){
            this.evaluate(function(total_hotel, city_code){
                var wsurl       = "http://localhost:9000/Cities/saveHotelNum";
                var data        = new Object();
                data.cityCode   = city_code;
                data.hotelNum   = -1;
                __utils__.sendAJAX(wsurl, "POST" , data, false, { contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
            }, total_hotel, city_code);

        }

        time2 = new Date();
        var diff = Math.abs(time1 - time2);
        this.echo("Execution time :"+diff+" ms");
    });

    date_counter++;
}
catch(e){
    casper.then(function(){
        this.echo("Error 12");
    });
}
```

The suspected cause is on this section :

```
this.evaluate(function(listHotelPage, city_code){}
```

I try to comment all code inside that evaluate code, but the crash still goes on...

But when I try to comment all that section, its goes pretty well. The crash was wiped out...

Once more, if I add another evaluating, which only echoing text like this (which replaced the evaluate code that I mentioned before)

```
this.evaluate(function(listHotelPage){
    window.__utils__.echo("List Hotel Page Length :"+listHotelPage.length);
}, listHotelPage);
```

It still produce a crash.

I still can't figure out why this happened. I think it's maybe caused of the use of evaluate code. But how can evaluting code can bring some chaos like this?

Any suggestions?

This is how `listHotelPage` is populated:

```
hotel_number    = this.evaluate(function(){ return document.querySelectorAll("div#dResult > div").length; });

//this.echo("Hotel Number :"+hotel_number);

listHotelObj = new Array();
for(var i=1; i<=parseInt(hotel_number); i++){
    category_len    = this.evaluate(function(i){ return document.querySelectorAll("div#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div:nth-child(1) > span > div").length; }, i);
    div_hotel_id    = this.evaluate(function(i){ return document.querySelector("div#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+")").id; }, i);
    hotel_code      = div_hotel_id.replace("Display", "");
    hotel_name      = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/strong/a[1]"));
    hotel_address   = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/em/label"));
    hotel_style     = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span"));
    hotel_location  = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span"));
    star_amount     = this.evaluate(function(i){ return document.querySelectorAll("#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+") > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > label > img").length; }, i);
    photo_url       = this.evaluate(function(i){ return document.querySelector("#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+") > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(1) > a > img").src; }, i);
    base64img       = this.base64encode(photo_url);
    star_score      = 0;

    var detail_url      = "http://www.mgholiday.com/b2b/Accom/HotelDescription.php?Code="+hotel_code;

    listDescriptionObj = new Array();

    for(var rows=1; rows <= category_len; rows++){
        room_category   = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/span/div["+rows+"]/div[1]/span"));
        room_service    = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/span/div["+rows+"]/div[2]/span"));
        room_price      = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/span/div["+rows+"]/div[3]/span"));
        image_src       = this.evaluate(function(rows, i){
            return jQuery("div#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div:nth-child(1) > span > div:nth-child("+rows+") > div:nth-child(4) > span > img")[0].src;
        }, rows, i);
        url_img_arr     = image_src.split("/");
        status_img      = url_img_arr[url_img_arr.length-1];

        if(status_img == "btnAV-v3.gif"){
            available = 1;
        }
        else{
            available = 0;
        }

        var price_part      = room_price.split(" "); //parse price, get online first array index (removing currency)
        var currencyCode    = price_part[1];
        var raw_price       = price_part[0].split(","); //split by comma
        var pure_price      = raw_price[0]; //get first array index of parsed_price

        for(var a=0; a<raw_price.length-1; a++){
            pure_price = pure_price * 1000;
        }

        descriptionObj                  = new Object();
        descriptionObj.room_category    = room_category;
        descriptionObj.room_service     = room_service;
        descriptionObj.room_price       = pure_price;
        descriptionObj.available        = available;
        descriptionObj.currencyCode     = currencyCode;

        listDescriptionObj.push(descriptionObj);
    }

    for(var rows=1; rows <= star_amount; rows++){
        var star_url            = this.evaluate(function(i, rows){ return document.querySelector("#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+") > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > label > img:nth-child("+rows+")").src; }, i, rows);
        var star_name_array     = star_url.split("/");
        var star_name           = star_name_array[star_name_array.length-1];

        if(star_name == "star1.gif"){
            star_score += 1;
        }
        if(star_name == "starh.gif"){
            star_score += 0.5;
        }
        if(star_name == "star0.gif"){
            star_score += 0;
        }
    }

    hotelObj                    = new Object();
    hotelObj.hotel_code         = hotel_code;
    hotelObj.hotel_name         = hotel_name;
    hotelObj.base64img          = base64img;
    hotelObj.star_score         = star_score;
    hotelObj.hotel_address      = hotel_address;
    hotelObj.hotel_location     = hotel_location;
    hotelObj.hotel_style        = hotel_style;
    hotelObj.hotel_address      = hotel_address;
    hotelObj.phone_number       = phone_number;
    hotelObj.fax_number         = fax_number;
    hotelObj.total_room         = total_room;

    hotelObj.listDescriptionObj = listDescriptionObj;

    listHotelObj.push(hotelObj);

}

pageResultObj               = new Object();
pageResultObj.page_num      = (page_iterator+1);
pageResultObj.listHotelObj  = listHotelObj;

listHotelPage.push(pageResultObj);

if(page_iterator < total_page-1){
    this.click(x("//*[@id='pg-top-cnt-"+(page_iterator+1)+"']"));
}
page_iterator++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for it.
It's not related with my listHotelPage.
The thing is, when I run the bulk of js code in evaluate function, it turns an error (crash of phantomjs), because evaluate cannot run or hold too much data.
I have tried to pass just listHotelPage and with a logical operation on it. The result is same, crash. But if the listHotelPage populating code is really needs, so here we go...

```
    hotel_number    = this.evaluate(function(){ return document.querySelectorAll("div#dResult > div").length; });

//this.echo("Hotel Number :"+hotel_number);

listHotelObj = new Array();
for(var i=1; i<=parseInt(hotel_number); i++){
    category_len    = this.evaluate(function(i){ return document.querySelectorAll("div#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div:nth-child(1) > span > div").length; }, i);
    div_hotel_id    = this.evaluate(function(i){ return document.querySelector("div#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+")").id; }, i);
    hotel_code      = div_hotel_id.replace("Display", "");
    hotel_name      = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/strong/a[1]"));
    hotel_address   = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/em/label"));
    hotel_style     = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span"));
    hotel_location  = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span"));
    star_amount     = this.evaluate(function(i){ return document.querySelectorAll("#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+") > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > label > img").length; }, i);
    photo_url       = this.evaluate(function(i){ return document.querySelector("#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+") > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(1) > a > img").src; }, i);
    base64img       = this.base64encode(photo_url);
    star_score      = 0;

    var detail_url      = "http://www.mgholiday.com/b2b/Accom/HotelDescription.php?Code="+hotel_code;

    listDescriptionObj = new Array();

    for(var rows=1; rows <= category_len; rows++){
        room_category   = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/span/div["+rows+"]/div[1]/span"));
        room_service    = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/span/div["+rows+"]/div[2]/span"));
        room_price      = this.fetchText(x("//*[@id='dResult']/div["+i+"]/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/span/div["+rows+"]/div[3]/span"));
        image_src       = this.evaluate(function(rows, i){
            return jQuery("div#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+") > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div:nth-child(1) > span > div:nth-child("+rows+") > div:nth-child(4) > span > img")[0].src;
        }, rows, i);
        url_img_arr     = image_src.split("/");
        status_img      = url_img_arr[url_img_arr.length-1];

        if(status_img == "btnAV-v3.gif"){
            available = 1;
        }
        else{
            available = 0;
        }

        var price_part      = room_price.split(" "); //parse price, get online first array index (removing currency)
        var currencyCode    = price_part[1];
        var raw_price       = price_part[0].split(","); //split by comma
        var pure_price      = raw_price[0]; //get first array index of parsed_price

        for(var a=0; a<raw_price.length-1; a++){
            pure_price = pure_price * 1000;
        }

        descriptionObj                  = new Object();
        descriptionObj.room_category    = room_category;
        descriptionObj.room_service     = room_service;
        descriptionObj.room_price       = pure_price;
        descriptionObj.available        = available;
        descriptionObj.currencyCode     = currencyCode;

        listDescriptionObj.push(descriptionObj);
    }

    for(var rows=1; rows <= star_amount; rows++){
        var star_url            = this.evaluate(function(i, rows){ return document.querySelector("#dResult > div:nth-child("+i+") > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > label > img:nth-child("+rows+")").src; }, i, rows);
        var star_name_array     = star_url.split("/");
        var star_name           = star_name_array[star_name_array.length-1];

        if(star_name == "star1.gif"){
            star_score += 1;
        }
        if(star_name == "starh.gif"){
            star_score += 0.5;
        }
        if(star_name == "star0.gif"){
            star_score += 0;
        }
    }

    hotelObj                    = new Object();
    hotelObj.hotel_code         = hotel_code;
    hotelObj.hotel_name         = hotel_name;
    hotelObj.base64img          = base64img;
    hotelObj.star_score         = star_score;
    hotelObj.hotel_address      = hotel_address;
    hotelObj.hotel_location     = hotel_location;
    hotelObj.hotel_style        = hotel_style;
    hotelObj.hotel_address      = hotel_address;
    hotelObj.phone_number       = phone_number;
    hotelObj.fax_number         = fax_number;
    hotelObj.total_room         = total_room;

    hotelObj.listDescriptionObj = listDescriptionObj;

    listHotelObj.push(hotelObj);

}

pageResultObj               = new Object();
pageResultObj.page_num      = (page_iterator+1);
pageResultObj.listHotelObj  = listHotelObj;

listHotelPage.push(pageResultObj);

if(page_iterator < total_page-1){
    this.click(x("//*[@id='pg-top-cnt-"+(page_iterator+1)+"']"));
}
page_iterator++;
```

Sorry my typing was missing...

Here we go...

I pull out my code from evaluate method...like this...

```
for(var i=0; i<listHotelPage.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj.length; j++){
        data                = new Object();
        data.hotelCode      = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].hotel_code;
        data.hotelName      = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].hotel_name;
        data.hotelAddress   = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].hotel_address;
        data.photo          = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].base64img;
        data.hotelStar      = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].star_score;
        data.cityCode       = city_code;

        this.evaluate(function(save_hotel_url, data){
            __utils__.sendAJAX(save_hotel_url, "POST" , data, false, { contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
        }, save_hotel_url, data);

        var room_length     = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj.length;
        var room_data       = new Object();
        var save_room_url   = "http://localhost:9000/Rooms/saveRoomRest";

        for(var k=0; k<room_length; k++){
            room_data = new Object();
            room_data.hotelCode     = data.hotelCode;
            room_data.categoryName  = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj[k].room_category;
            room_data.roomService   = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj[k].room_service;
            room_data.roomPrice     = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj[k].room_price;
            room_data.available     = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj[k].available;
            room_data.currencyCode  = listHotelPage[i].listHotelObj[j].listDescriptionObj[k].currencyCode;

            this.evaluate(function(save_room_url, room_data){
                __utils__.sendAJAX(save_room_url, "POST" , room_data, false, { contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
            }, save_room_url, room_data);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I pull out the for loop outside the evaluate function, so it will bring lesser execution for evaluate...
On the last section, the this.evaluate function only evaluating `__utils__.sendAJAX(save_room_url, "POST" , room_data, false, { contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
On the previous example, all iteration code and all scraped data was executed in this.evaluate()`

Comment: It seems evaluate cannot execute too much instructions at one time.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. The first snippet is not executed inside of `evaluate`. Do you mean that you send the data one by one to the server instead of all at once?

Comment: The first code which I attach is executing the logical code inside evaluate function. You can see this code 
this.evaluate(function(listHotelPage, city_code){ code } at the very first code which I attach. There are much code inside that evaluate. Also, its evaluate function has passed with lots of data (listHotelPage).
When I remove the listHotelPage value from the evaluate method, the crash has gone.

Comment: The first code edited. Now you can see I do some iteration inside evaluate function, and send the value one by one to the server. This is because I'm using REST for storing data to my database, so it takes one by one sendAJAX execution...
More clearly, you can see the evaluate function after this code :
this.echo("Saved Hotel With Amount = "+total_hotel); at the first snippet of code

Comment: In the first snippet in your *answer* I see a lot of small `evaluate` calls. The code wouldn't work if it were completely enclosed in `evaluate`, because you cannot call `evaluate` or `fetchText` from inside of an `evaluate` callback. The very first line is a single `evaluate`.

Comment: the fetchText was executed outside evaluate. On the first snippet at my answer, the evaluate doesn't execute fetchText. Only this.
hotel_number    = this.evaluate(function(){ return document.querySelectorAll("div#dResult > div").length; });
That's why the crash has not comes from listHotelPage data populating

Comment: For comparing, you can see the first snippet at my question, and the second snippet at my answer, look at the for loop.
for(var i=0; i<listHotelPage.length; i++){} [at first snippet code at question] and 
for(var i=0; i<listHotelPage.length; i++){} [at second snippet code at answer]
Then you'll figure out what makes the second code at my answer different with the first snippet at my question